# What does module refer to in context of the 4 concepts of Webpack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

The [4 concepts of webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) are **Entry**, **Output**, **Loaders**, and **Plugins**.

I have been looking through the documentation to get an understanding of how my React configuration works.

Entry and Output make sense.  But why is loaders included under module.

In terms of the documentation modules are what webpack creates from files.

But in the code ( working ) it holds `loaders`.

I would have expected it to be a 3rd key.

Where is the documentation for Webpack-React?  I did an advance Google Search but nothing relevant came up except a [React Proxy Loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/react-proxy-loader/),

I am trying to understand this code and need a starting point. Other than the 4 primary concepts.  I don't know how it works.

The form below does not even seem to be contained in more in depth documentation under [loaders](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-class-properties"],
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: *"In terms of the documentation modules are what webpack creates from files."* What makes you say that? From the [Modules](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/) documentation it's clear that modules are things programmers write (as files, true), not Webpack. Similarly, the [Loaders documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#loaders) is fairly clear about the relationship between Loaders and modules: *"...webpack loaders transform all types of files into modules that can be included in your application's dependency graph."*

Comment: *"What does module refer to in context of the 4 concepts of web pack?"* and *"Where is the documentation for Webpack-React?"* are entirely separate questions, they shouldn't be conflated into a single question. (The latter is also off-topic. Please see [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic))

Comment: (It *does* seem odd that "module" isn't one of the [five] concepts of Webpack. Indeed, the first of the five. Just to set the stage if nothing else.)

Comment: @T.J. - Module is the probably the most over-used terms in all of computer science behind Objects.  That is why I specified in the context of Webpack in the question itself.  The authors say that they convert files to modules.  In this context modules are "things" that it can create a dependency graph from and then combine to form a bundle.

Comment: The main issue is documentation.  How long do I have to search the web to find documentation for the code above.  I've posted 2 separate places I've looked now.

Comment: I agree its confusing. did you read this already? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/

Comment: Someone from github got back to me and told me this form is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

So one answer to your question is that you're not necessarily looking for documentation for Webpack and React, but Babel (or similar transpiler) and React. Babel-loader (which is the loader you're using above) transpiles React's JSX format into javascript the browser can read via Webpack. Here's the [babel-loader documentation](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/).

Here are a few other resources that may help:

1) [Setup React.js with Npm, Babel 6 and Webpack in under 1 hour](https://medium.com/@fastlane80/setup-react-js-with-npm-babel-6-and-webpack-in-under-1-hour-1a714f973506)

2) [Setup a React Environment Using webpack and Babel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setup-a-react-environment-using-webpack-and-babel)

3) [React JSX transform](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx#react)

4) And if it is of interest to you: [React without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: I knew I was using Babel, but I was not aware that it handles all my React code - both JSX and ES6.  Thanks.

Comment: I guess that is technically correct as JSX is an extension to the language.